# How to get dictionary and array from 'http://country.io/names.json'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to json.

I want to know that how can I get code and name of country from

http://country.io/names.json

and display it in label.

I only want to know objectForKEy and valueForKey for this.

I want output like,

[image: Before Country Name, I want Country Code from API]

I want Output like,

```
IN  India
```

In my tableView

I have two label in my cell, one for Code and another for name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
NSMutableArray *Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://country.io/names.json"]];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

for (NSString *findkey in [json allKeys]) {
    //[Name addObject:[json objectForKey:findkey]];
      [Name addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",findkey,[json objectForKey:findkey]]];
}

NSLog(@"Name==%@",Name);
```

**you get output like**

[image]

Comment: thanks, I got the country name. But I also want code from that. So how can I get that? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: If I use allValues than app is crashing. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: what the output you need

Comment: I wrote like this - for (NSString *findkeyValue in [json allValues]) {
        [Code addObject:[json valueForKey:findkeyValue]];
    }  @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @KAR - simple buddy, what the output you expect , can you show some sample

Comment: I have added one image in question please refer that. @Anbu.karthik